# Horizontal line in Shap values dependence plot behind plotted points

Tags: r, ggplot2, shap

I am using the `shapviz` package to plot Shap dependence plots. I would like to add a horizontal line at y=0 to the plot, and I would like it to be plotted behind the Shap points. So far I was just able to plot the line on top of the points, as shown by the example code below:

```
# Load required libraries
library(fastshap)
library(shapviz)
library(randomForest)

# Load example data
data(iris)

#Run a ML model
model <- randomForest::randomForest(Sepal.Width ~ ., data = iris)

#Calculate SHAP values
shap_values= fastshap::explain(model,
                               X=iris[,!names(iris) %in% c("Sepal.Width")],
                               pred_wrapper=predict,
                               nsim=5)

#Dependece plot for "Petal.Length"
shp=shapviz(shap_values,X=iris[,!names(iris) %in% c("Sepal.Width")])
plot <- sv_dependence(shp, v="Petal.Length", color_var="Petal.Length")

#Add a horizontal line on 0
plot + geom_hline(yintercept=0, color = "darkgrey")
```

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit hacky but you could manipulate the `ggplot` object returned by `sv_dependence` directly and add your `geom_hline` layer at the first position to the list of `layers` like so.

```r
library(fastshap)
library(shapviz)
library(ggplot2)

# Dependece plot for "Petal.Length"
shp <- shapviz(shap_values, X = iris[, !names(iris) %in% c("Sepal.Width")])
plot <- sv_dependence(shp, v = "Petal.Length", color_var = "Petal.Length", 
                      color = "red", size = 4)

plot$layers <- c(
  list(geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color = "black")),
  plot$layers
)

plot
```

[image]